# Molecular visualization software for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: computational-chemistry, software

I've been using our lab's code [MCMD](https://github.com/khavernathy/mcmd) on my Raspberry Pi for fun and exploratory purposes. I'm trying to find a VMD, Avogadro, Ovito, or other equivalent that is usable on Raspberry Pi, e.g. to view .xyz or .pdb molecular dynamics trajectories, or simply single-state structures. I have found none so far; I'm using Raspbian OS.

Comment: When I tried first RPi long time ago I swear it was as easy as `apt-get install openbabel  avogadro pymol jmol rasmol` (there might be some extra packages you need to install), but I never really used it due to miserable performance and constant issues due to ARM CPU. Also, isn't it Rasp**b**ian?:)

Comment: Avogadro should be available from the raspbian repos: `sudo apt-get install avogadro`.

Comment: To search what packages are available for Raspbian: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1179/does-raspbians-repository-have-a-browsable-package-list

Comment: very nice, ty all.

Comment: vmd has "support" for arm64 archetechtures, now, though not for raspberry pi. all of the config options, will set CUDA, which you will not have. I have been trying it this weekend, but it seems to fail at every turn, and there is no documentation of anyone getting VMD to work, yet. I think I came close, in a method of rewriting the installation, makefiles, config scripts, and startup scripts. VMD is kinda spaghetti code. I cant get it running on any ARM based machine, but there is code in the source files for that.